# What should I do about a bad question that cannot be improved?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, quality-improvement

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69514660/2725810) based on a wrong premise I got from Google searches (with search terms driven by wrong assumptions). I do regret not looking up documentation before asking.

Now the question is closed, but is continuing to accumulate downvotes.

I do not want to delete the question, because it has an answer (with some helpful information). I cannot improve on the question, because the whole premise of the question is insufficient research.

What can I do to prevent this question from damaging my reputation without a limit?

Comment: You couldn't delete it even if you wanted to (the answer has a score of 2).

Comment: @Tomerikoo [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Forget about reputation loss, write better posts, and move on. 1 upvote already recovers 5 downvotes. Also, you probably don't want to incur further [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/2821954) on that post...

Comment: Did you read [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: There's not really much you can do about it if the question can't be improved. The most important lesson here is to do more research before posting a question. Since you've already realized that, you've done pretty much all that can be done. Also, with your rep, I doubt the downvotes/rep loss will make any material difference, at least as far as bans go. I would suggest letting this one go.

Comment: If you unaccept the answer, it would be automagically deleted.

Comment: You really should... *improve it*! Incorporate the confusion that you've explained here and in the comments into the question itself. Make it so that the question is *not* unclear, just simple/easy/obvious. Then, it can be re-opened. No way to stop downvotes, of course, but that is not something you should worry too much about. Those are just people who feel that your question is not all that useful to future viewers, and they may well be right. But that doesn't make the question inappropriate, unsuitable, or bad.

Comment: @CodyGray Re-opened? For what purpose?

Comment: Because there's no need for it to be closed! It was only closed because of a lack of clarity, and that can be trivially addressed with an edit.

Comment: @CodyGray I believe (but am not sure) that the way this question appears now is after an edit that I made after the question had been closed. Is the question still unclear?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It's still missing context - where does this question come from? The comments hold the context - you are applying C++ knowledge to Python. And through the power of the internet you found poorly written documentation written by Joe Anybody that supports assumptions you would make when you attack Python from the perspective of another language. I feel your pain, sometimes everything that can go wrong will go wrong.

Comment: As others have said, it can definitely be improved, it was just closed because it was unclear. In my opinion, the best way to improve it would be to explain exactly what you expect `=` to do and why, and what exactly went wrong when you tried to run your second code block. [Here](https://pastebin.com/jKNH7s10) is a suggestion about how to do this, feel free to use it if you like it. I think it's an interesting question, and it would be a shame if it doesn't get improved.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Thank you! Done. You might want to post this comment as reply, so I can accept it and link to it from the note in the re-written question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Done.

Comment: At least you did and showed your research. Most others don't do that. I think that one conclusion could be that a quick search is not sufficient enough for asking on SO. The likelihood of asking a question again that already has been asked is so big, that one has to really search for a longer time before asking. If only all people would do that.

Comment: You have to develop a thick skin about downvotes. It's very hard to know why people downvote a question, because they don't have to tell you; the downvote gives you no useful feedback, so there is no action you can usefully take in response unless people also comment and explain. (That's why I've always argued that downvotes without explanation shouldn't be allowed - but I usually get downvoted, without explanation, for expressing this opinion.) If it helps you retain your self-respect, just assume, in the absence of evidence to the contrary, that the downvotes are malicious and/or wrong.

Comment: @MichaelKay I really take issue with that suggestion to assume that anonymous downvotes are "malicious and/or wrong". Downvoting is supposed to be anonymous, and that's entirely by-design. Just because someone does not want to reveal how they voted does not make their downvote illegitimate, and it certainly doesn't imply malintent. One of the key behaviors expected of all users on this site is to *assume good intentions*; your advice runs counter to that. It's perfectly fine to consciously choose to ignore the feedback provided by a downvote with which you disagree, but not to assume malice.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not saying the downvotes don't mean anything. I'm just saying you have no way of knowing what they mean, so don't let them get you down. If people can't be bothered to tell you what's wrong with your question or answer, don't spend time fretting about it, just ignore them.

Comment: Ignoring downvotes, especially multiple, is not good advice. The implication is that the content is *not good*. That needs correcting.

Comment: @Gimby Guessing what the downvoters think might be wrong is a waste of your time. You have no way of knowing. And you have no idea whether they are experts or fools. React to the comments, certainly, but not to the downvotes. (Actually, very often when I get downvoted it's because I've expressed an opinion, like "always use short variable names", and it's fairly obvious that the downvoters simply disagree with my opinion. Well, it's only an opinion, and I'm not going to change it because someone disagrees and can't be bothered to say why.)

Comment: I've had two unexplained downvotes today. One for an answer that is absolutely explicit and absolutely correct. The other for a question that had already been closed as a duplicate (it was indeed a duplicate, but my careful attempts to search for an answer to my problem had failed to locate it). So I stick with my thesis: there is absolutely no point in worrying about downvotes.

Comment: @MichaelKay That's the kicker! Downvoters don't need to explain *anything*, it's not specifically their job. Don't try to link quality voting to providing and receiving feedback, they are entirely unrelated processes. Anyone can post an explanation, you don't need to cast a vote to be able to explain what can be improved. If you have a problem with a lack of feedback that's on all of us, don't make people who cast quality votes the boogeyman.

Answer (score 33):

Is it really a bad question?

Let's consider this scenario:

In 6 to 8 weeks someone else has a similar line of reasoning as you did and does the similar sloppy search on Google. How awesome would it be if not an article from geeksforgeeks pops up high in the Google ranking but your question with its accepted and positive scoring answer?

I think that would be pretty awesome.

So now you have to retrace your search process: What terms did you search for? What key concepts crossed your mind while working on that problem? What alternative wording did you consider?

Once you have that list, you can see if you can include extra words, terms, concepts, in your question so the next Google visitor is highly likely to get your question as a search hit. If you succeed, you made the internet a better place, despite having asked a question that isn't deemed useful by the experts here.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that it's not a bad question. In fact, it's a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value) with, at the time of writing, 64 upvotes and 1 downvote. Since your question is largely the same as a question which the community considers good, we can suppose that your question is also good, at least if we consider it in isolation on its own merits.

However, since it is a duplicate, I've used my gold badge privilege to close yours. (Yours will continue to exist and be searchable; closing it as a duplicate simply means that you and anyone else who finds your question can find more answers by following the link.)

Comment: I do not program in Python, but if the question is indeed a duplicate of another page, then Stack Overflow will not suffer any content loss if: all relevant advice provide on your question exists or is transferred to the dupe target AND the crux of your question and relevant keywords exist or are transferred to the dupe target.  To counter what Cody said, if a page is close-worthy for any reason (even if not the current close reason and regardless of clarifying edits), then the page should not be reopened.  I am pretty firm in my stance that SO needs better eggs in better&fewer baskets.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't disagree with what you said. I do not think we should reopen questions that should be closed for some reason. Before kaya did, no one had proposed this as a duplicate. If it is a duplicate, I obviously do not think it should be reopened. What I am opposed to is closing a question because it seems "too basic" or "RTFM", or because it was based on some misunderstanding. Future viewers may well have these basic questions arising from a misunderstanding.

Comment: The question has since been reopened... :/

Comment: We could maybe even stop displaying scores of questions closed as duplicate. After all, people will only be interested in the score of the duplicate target.

Comment: Actually, I would contest that the two questions are duplicates. They both ask about the same topic, but they are phrased rather differently. The question that is now pointed to as the target of the duplicate tag asks why Python is designed the way it is, and the accepted answer gives an opinion as to why this is a good design choice. The question being asked here asks why a particular construct does not work in Python, and what the programmer should use instead. That's not the same question, although much of the material in the accepted answer is relevant to both questions.

Comment: @MichaelKay I suppose you could interpret the OP's question here as meaning *"what makes this a syntax error in Python?"* such that the answer would be *"because `<assignment-target> = <expression>` is not a production rule for an expression in the Python language grammar"*, but that doesn't seem to be all that useful an answer. The more understandable summary of that - that assignment is a statement in Python rather than an expression - is present in the linked duplicate Q&A, anyway.

Comment: Compare with the many questions closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) in Java about null pointer exceptions - most of which want to fix a specific piece of code, not learn about general methods of debugging programs which throw null pointer exceptions. As I understand, the general rule is that if the other Q&A contains the answer then it's a duplicate. I think that clearly applies here, even if they are phrased differently.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your question can definitely be improved. It was closed because it wasn't detailed enough or clear enough, not because there was anything wrong with what was being asked. In fact, I think it's an interesting question and it would be a shame if it weren't improved. I learned something from it, and I wouldn't be surprised if others did too.

To improve it, you need to make it more detailed and more clear. Here are a few suggestions about how you can do that:

- Explain how you expect `=` to behave and why. As it is, someone who knows Python but not C++ (or some other language where `=` behaves as you expect) might have a hard time understanding what your second code block is supposed to do.
- Explain exactly what went wrong when you tried to run your second code block. You say that you "can't do this", but you don't say why. It would be better to include a clear problem statement, like "this code gives me a syntax error".

Here is a suggestion for how you can rewrite your question so that it can be reopened, feel free to use it if you like it:

> Consider:
>
> ```
> course_db = Course(title='Databases')
> course_db.save()
> ```
>
> Coming from a C++ background, I would expect `(course_db = Course(title='Databases'))` to behave like it would in C++, that is
> assign `Course(title='Databases')` to `course_db` *and return the
> assigned object so that I can use it as part of a larger expression*.
> For example, I would expect this code to do the same thing as the code
> above:
>
> ```
> (course_db = Course(title='Databases')).save()
> ```
>
> But when I tried this, I got a syntax error.
>
> Why can't I do this in Python, and what can I do instead?

Comment: Note: I wrote this answer to expand on a comment that I wrote before the question was improved. As I write this answer, the question has already been improved and reopened.

Comment: The presentation of the question may have been improved, but it's still a dupe and should not have been reopened. Unfortunately the people who reopened it did not give any explanation for why they think it's not a dupe.

Comment: @kaya3 Duplicates don't have to be bad. My answer explains how to improve it so that it doesn't have to be closed as "needs details or clarity" as it was before. Whether or not it's a duplicate is unrelated. But it's true that I would be curious to know why some people don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed, it can still be worth improving questions that are dupes. But I think when you edit them it goes into the review queue, and I guess some people might miss that it was closed as a dupe rather than some other reason.

Comment: @kaya3 In this specific case, it was edited as I suggested while it was closed as "needs details or clarity", which means that at the time reopening after the edit was appropriate. It was only later closed as a duplicate (and reopened again for some reason). As a side note, [they recently made a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/349538) so that it's possible to edit a closed question without sending it to the review queue.